# Checking my Tuple code

Tags: python, replace, fastq

So I'm trying to parce a FastQ sequence, but I'm a beginner to Python, and I'm a little confused as to how to complete my code. This is what the program is supposed to carry out:

if I enter the FASTQ seqname line...

```
@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393
```

...then the program will output:

```
Instrument = EAS139
Run ID = 136
Flow Cell ID = FC706VJ
Flow Cell Lane = 2
Tile Number = 2104
X-coord = 15343
Y-coord = 197393
```

Here's my (incomplete) code:

```
    class cleaner:
    def __init__(self,str):
        self.str = seq.upper()
    def line (self):
        1 = inStr.replace ('@',' ').replace (':',' ').split (' ')
newTuple =(float(1[1]),float(1[2))] #...etc                


    def printInstrument (self):
        print ("Instrument: {0}".format(float(1[1])))
    def printRunID (self):
        print ("Run ID: {0}".format(float(1[2])))
    def printFlowCellID (self):
        print ("Flow Cell ID: {0}".format(float(1[3])))
    def printFlowCellLane (self):
        print ("Flow Cell Lane: {0}".format(float(1[4])))
    def printTileNumber (self):
        print ("Tile Number{0}".format(float(1[5])))
    def printX (self):
        print ("X-coordinate:{0}".format(float(1[6])))
    def printY (self):
        print ("y-coordinate: {0}".format(float(1[7])))
 def main():
    seq = input('Enter FastQ sequence:')


main()
```

Comment: to further clarify, this is what the program should do: "if I enter the FASTQ seqname line “@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393” (without quotes), then the program will output:
Instrument = EAS139
Run ID = 136
Flow Cell ID = FC706VJ
Flow Cell Lane = 2
Tile Number = 2104
X-coord = 15343
Y-coord = 197393"

Comment: Put that comment in the question! Just edit it in. Any new relevant information should always go in your question. :)

Comment: `"@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393"[1:].split(':')`

Comment: @Human, I just did :-), @user3504701, in these cases, click on the `edit` link below the question. It will allow you to add text and stuff

Comment: @user3504701, I added the output to the question but I didn't want to change your indentation. Are you sure that's correct? Because you'd get an `Exception` if you try to run that. Is that the case or is just that your indentation got messed up when you posted the question?

Comment: You're going to get an Exception no matter how you slice it because `(float(1[1]),float(1[2))]` isn't even close to valid Python syntax.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fair point, I didn't even get to that part... I stopped after the `__class__` :-D

Answer (score 1):

If your input is like that, remove the first character (the `@`), split the string by `:` and then zip the values you'll obtain by doing that to a pre-set of keys:

```
>>> keys=["Instrument", "Run ID", "Flow Cell ID", "Flow Cell Lane", "Title Number", "X-coord", "Y-coord"]
>>> values="@EAS139:136:FC706VJ:2:2104:15343:197393"[1:].split(':')
>>> my_dict=dict(zip(keys, values))
>>> for key, val in my_dict.iteritems():
...     print "%s: %s" % (key, val)
...
Run ID: 136
Flow Cell ID: FC706VJ
Title Number: 2104
Y-coord: 197393
X-coord: 15343
Flow Cell Lane: 2
Instrument: EAS139
```

I strongly recommend that you check:

- Slicing strings ([here](https://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/strings.html))
- What the split function does to an string
- What a dict is ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict))
- What zip does ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip))

Comment: @user3504701 I just updated my question... I think you should check the links I provided **:)**